# Testing if belongsTo relationship has been populated

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a ember-data model which has a `belongsTo` relationship and I'd like test whether there is any value (aka, foreign key reference) in this relationship. I initially thought I could just state:

```
if(myModel.rel !== null) {
    // do something now that belongsTo relationship has a value
}
```

But of course this doesn't work because `myModel.rel` would never be null and instead is some sort of Ember Data object. Ok fine. I adjusted this to:

```
if(myModel.rel.content !== null) {
    // do something now that belongsTo relationship has a value
}
```

This does work but I feel like maybe this is a bit too "hacky" ... is there a cleaner, more API driven way of stating this conditional in Ember Data?

Comment: There is no existing API yet, but it may be added: https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/issues/163

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I have done it this way (I don't know of an `official` way).

```
if (model.get('relationshipName.id')) {
  // there's and ID present, so it means theres a value for the foreign key
}
```

`model.relationshipName.id` returns `undefined` when there's no value and the id when there's a value.

Comment: Note that this is less useful if you want to check the existence of a relationship that isn't yet persisted, because it may not have an ID yet.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Ember-Data there is an API to get the value of a relationship like so:

```js
model.belongsTo('relationshipName').value()
```

And then you can use the `isPresent` helper to check against `null` or `undefined` in a more idiomatic way:

```js
import { isPresent } from '@ember/utils';

const relatedRecord = model.belongsTo('relationshipName').value();
const relatedRecordExists = isPresent(relatedRecord);
```

Or simply use the return value in an `if` statement without coercing to boolean, e.g.:

```js
if (relatedRecord) {
  ...
}
```

### References

- [Ember-Data API Docs - belongsTo method on Model](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/4.1/classes/Model/methods/belongsTo?anchor=belongsTo)
- [Ember-Data API Docs - BelongsToReference](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/4.1/classes/BelongsToReference)
- [Ember API Docs - isPresent util](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.1/functions/@ember%2Futils/isPresent)